# SPARQL How to print the data without data scheme

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, protege

I have this ontology model:

```
SensorOntology:MedicalCabinet-01 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                               SensorOntology:MedicalCabinetSensor ;
                      SensorOntology:hasId "57"^^xsd:int ;
                      SensorOntology:hasValue "0"^^xsd:int .
```

I wrote this query

```
SELECT ?sensor ?value
WHERE { ?sensor:hasId "51"^^xsd:int.
        ?sensor :hasValue ?value}
```

The result is this

```
    sensor            |  value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MedicalCabinet-01 | "0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>
```

Is it any way to print this:

```
    sensor            |  value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MedicalCabinet-01 | 0
```

I don't want to print `^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mean and want to omit is the datatype IRI of the RDF literal:

> A literal in an RDF graph consists of two or three elements:
>
> - a **lexical form**, being a Unicode [UNICODE] string, which should be in
>     Normal Form C [NFC],
> - a **datatype IRI**, being an IRI identifying a
>     datatype that determines how the lexical form maps to a literal value,
>     and
> - ...

The lexical form of a literal can be returned by the function [`STR`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str)(note, it will be a string then):

```sql
SELECT ?sensor (STR(?val) as ?value)
WHERE { ?sensor:hasId "51"^^xsd:int.
        ?sensor :hasValue ?val}
```